# how to pass parameter while sourcing script file

Tags: tcl, parameter-passing

i was sourcing a tcl script file and could not pass the parameter.
ie.

```
source test.tcl param1 param2
```

where in `test.tcl`, it uses `param1` and `param2` to print as string

Note: I need to source tcl script only.. Not any other

```
puts "param1                       :  $1"
puts "param2                       :  $2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `argv`:

```
set origargv $::argv
set ::argv [list -param1 x -param2 y]
source myscript
```

The sourced script can access the parameters from `argv` as usual.

Comment: I'd use a `try…finally` to restore the arguments… if necessary. I usually don't write my scripts to need that; most of my code files just declare procedures, namespaces and classes, and have no meaningful arguments.